# ASP using a lot of memory

Tags: iis, iis-7, memory, asp.net

We are struggling with hosting one of our web applications on an IIS7-server. This server hosts multiple web applications, each with their own application pool.

A simple MVC5 app, consisting of two models and a couple of views with a form uses 3 to 500 megabytes of memory. This is quite a lot for such a simple application. Because it's such a simple app, we are quite sure that there are no memory leaks from our side.

We were wondering why so much memory is needed and if this can be limited one way or another. We already tried setting a limit on the virtual and physical memory for recycling, but still, no solution.

Edit:
A solution to our problem, but not posting as an answer just yet because the why is still not completely clear:

Removing an external library (Telerik Kendo MVC) completely solved our problems. Removing the DLL and the references caused the memory use to drop to very managable levels (between 80 and 200). I understand why this is the case and can think of various reasons that this is causing high memory use.

They also have a front end version of this library, so I tested it with this. If I add the javascript library and call some of their most basic elements, I get the same high memory use. Why and how does a javascript library impact server-side memory use?

Comment: restart the application and have process monitor record it while its running, analyse what the application is doing under the hood, there might be a driver blowing up or similar.

Comment: How much traffic does the app get? Does it maintain session state? Does the app pool immediately consume that much memory, or does it grow over time?  It may not be a memory leak, but even a simple app could have them, e.g. from database connections not being closed.

Comment: None (yet, fortunately this was during testing), from the start. Barely use sessions.